# Mocking Mongoose model with jest

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs

I am trying to mock a mongoose model with `jest`, but is getting `Cannot create property 'constructor' on number '1'` error. I was able to reproduce the issue by creating the project with 2 files shown below. Is there a way to mock a mongoose model with `jest`?

./model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const schema = new Schema({
  name: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Test', schema)
```

./model.test.js

```
jest.mock('./model')
const Test = require('./model')

// Test.findOne.mockImplementation = () => {
//   ...
// }
```

Error:

```
 FAIL  ./model.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot create property 'constructor' on number '1'

      at ModuleMockerClass._generateMock (../../jitta/sandbox/rest_api/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:458:34)
      at Array.forEach (native)
      at Array.forEach (native)
      at Array.forEach (native)
```

**Update:**

Seems to be a bug in jest.
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3073

Comment: Not sure about jest but [mockgoose](https://github.com/mockgoose/mockgoose) was an easier option for me than trying to mock everything.

Answer (score 30):

An other solution is to `spyOn` the model `prototype` functions.

For example, this will make `MyModel.save()` fail :

```
    jest.spyOn(MyModel.prototype, 'save')
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject('fail update'))
```

You can use `mockImplementationOnce` to not having to `mockRestore` the spy. But you can also use `mockImplementation` and use something like :

```
afterEach(() => {
  jest.restoreAllMocks()
})
```

Tested with `"mongoose": "^4.11.7"` and `"jest": "^23.6.0"`.

Comment: Is there an option to inspect the object it has been invoked on? `mockImplementationOnce` and co. don't accept any arguments on `save`, as the method itself is without arguments. Same logic applies to `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(argument)` - `argument` is `undefined`.

Comment: after spending a day figuring this out --- this answer helped! thanks

Answer (score 15):

ok, i had the same problem so i author this package to solve this problem:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockingoose

this is how you can use it let's say this is your model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const schema = Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})

export default mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

and this is your test:

```
it('should find', () => {
  mockingoose.User.toReturn({ name: 2 });

  return User
  .find()
  .where('name')
  .in([1])
  .then(result => {
    expect(result).toEqual({ name: 2 });
  })
});
```

checkout the tests folder for more examples:
[https://github.com/alonronin/mockingoose/blob/master/___tests___/index.test.js](https://github.com/alonronin/mockingoose/blob/master/___tests___/index.test.ts)

no connections is made to the database!

Comment: What about nested documents?

Comment: @EgorMalkevich shouldn't be no problem.

Comment: Does this work with `static` and `method` on a `model`?

Comment: Update: turns out it does. Was just using the wrong operation.

Comment: would this work with a controller test, if the controller imports the model?

Comment: Thank you @AlonValadji ... I tried it, but unfortunately it's very slow!

Answer (score 2):

for typescript I found a hack that works

`jest.spyOn(model, 'find').mockReturnValueOnce(dummyData as any);`

Answer (score 0):

Mockingoose seems to be a very nice solution. But I was also able to mock my model with `Jest.mock()` function. At least `create` method.

```
// in the module under the test I am creating (saving) DeviceLocation to DB
// someBackendModule.js
...
DeviceLocation.create(location, (err) => {
...
});
...
```

DeviceLocation model definition:

```
// DeviceLocation.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { Schema } = mongoose;
const modelName = 'deviceLocation';

const DeviceLocation = new Schema({
...
});

export default mongoose.model(modelName, DeviceLocation, modelName);
```

DeviceLocation mock in the `__mocks__` folder in the same folder as `DeviceLocation` model:

```
// __mock__/DeviceLocation.js
export default {
    create: (x) => {    
        return x;
    },
};
```

in the test file:

```
// test.js
// calling the mock
...
jest.mock('../../src/models/mongoose/DeviceLocation');
import someBackendModule from 'someBackendModule';
...
// perform the test
```