# NestJs failes to compile testing module when running tests with Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs

I have a `CategoryService` that is a provider of `CategoriesModule`:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
            {
                name: Category.name,
                imports: [EventEmitterModule],
                inject: [EventEmitter2],
                useFactory: (eventEmitter: EventEmitter2) => {
                    const schema = CategorySchema
                    schema.post('findOneAndDelete', (category: CategoryDocument) => eventEmitter.emit(CollectionEvents.CategoriesDeleted, [category]))
                    return schema
                }
            }
        ])
    ],
  providers: [CategoriesService]
})
export class CategoriesModule {
}
```

My `CategoriesService` is:

```
@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService {
    constructor(@InjectModel(Category.name) private categoryModel: Model<CategoryDocument>) {
    }

    ...
}
```

Then I have a jest test file of that service `categories.service.spec.ts`:

```
describe('CategoriesService', () => {
    let service: CategoriesService

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [CategoriesService]
        }).compile()

        service = module.get<CategoriesService>(CategoriesService)
    })

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined()
    })
})
```

But when i run the test (using nestJs built in script `test`) if failes with this error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CategoriesService (?). Please make sure that the argument CategoryModel at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - If CategoryModel is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
    - If CategoryModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing CategoryModel */ ]
      })
```

But I don't get it, when running the server using `npm start` it all runs ok,
and here it complains about `CategoryModel`, why?

Answer (score 2):

Category model is used in `CategoryService` and hence is a dependency for `CategoryService`. You will need to add the model to your spec file so that the dependency is resolved.
If you are using mongoose look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45001150/11684622) it will help you.